# XText Validation - Get the raw input during validation

Tags: java, antlr, xtext, xtend

I'm writing a grammar that has an existing validator. I'd like to use the existing validator to validate the code, and integrate it with the built in XText validation mechanism, so it will work seamlessley.

How can I :

A) - Access the raw code so I can pass it to the external validator?

B) - Having parsed the output of the validator, pass the result back to the eclipse UI?

Comment: I think a question about accessing the raw code when it's only obvious how to access the AST is fairly well formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to have access to the textual part of the model aka "node model" `NodeModelUtils` will give you helper methods to get the node for an EObject.

Alternatively your `EObject` may have a `eResource`which may be a `XtextResource`which may have a `parseResult`which gives you access to the `rootNode`.

you can always ask an `INode`for its text.

you have to do creating the Xtext Errors from your "other Parsers" errors yourself manually.